# Append Firebase data to an array in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I don't know what I am doing wrong! I just simply want to take data from Firebase database and iterate for each result and put them into an array. I have tried serval different approaches. But they all return results adding one at a time to the array. Resulting in an array looking like this:

```
["1"]
["1","2"]
["1","2","3"]
["1","2","3","4"]
```

as you can see it adds one object each time it iterates.
Here is what I have:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")
ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    userUrl = snapshot.value?["profile_image_1"] as! String
    imageArray.insert(userUrl, atIndex: 0)
}, withCancelBlock: { error in
    print(error.description)
})
```

and I have also tried this:

```
let userUrl = (snapshot.value.objectForKey("profile_image_1")) as! String
imageArray.append(userUrl)
```

I just want to put each result into an array I can access the data at once, outside of the completion block.

```
["1","2","3","4"]
```

Any help would be great!

Database:
[Firebase Database Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsmm8.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var imageArray = []

func appendData(){
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users") 

    ref.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        var tempImageArray = []

        for user in snapshot.children {
            userUrl = user.value?["profile_image_1"] as? String
            self.imageArray.insert(userUrl, atIndex: 0)
            tempImageArray.append(broadcastItem)
        }

        self.imageArray = tempImageArray
    })
}
```

edit: I updated the code, please try this.

Comment: This is what I get: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value `let userUrl = snapshot.value?["profile_image_1"] as! String`

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your database structure in Firebase? This error seems like the "profile_image_1" doesn't return a string but depending on your structure it can be an easy fix.

Comment: I added an image of my database to my question.

Comment: Change the as! String to as? String and see if that will fix it. It could be that not all your users have the profile_image_1.

Comment: Adding "?"  (optional) to the **as** did not work. Here is how I got it to work: `for user in snapshot.children {
                let childSnapshot = snapshot.childSnapshotForPath(user.key)
                let userUrl = childSnapshot.value?["profile_image_1"] as? String
                imageArray.insert(userUrl!, atIndex: 0)
            }` and that shows all of the urls in an array correctly, except for it repeats the array 9 times, and that is the number of users images in the db. It repeats the array for each user, a total of 9. I only want it to show a single array.

Comment: Any solutions so far?

Comment: @Barrett I've updated the code, can you give it a try?

Comment: That did it! Thank you for your help Jordi.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer the question directly but I'm assuming you want to access the final data after everything is appended.

I had the same problem and I came about it by doing the same exact thing you are doing then I created a dispatchQueue inside the completion block.

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("users")

ref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
    userUrl = snapshot.value?["profile_image_1"] as! String
    imageArray.insert(userUrl, atIndex: 0)

 DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

 //access the final array here.

  }
})
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This code will not work because you are still accessing the array within the observe block which is triggered by a single observation from the Firebase.